# Images are not getting populate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to load the sliding images in a web app and for that I'm using Bootstrap carousel. Fetched the images from the backend. The images are stored in the images state. Below is the JSON format of the data getting fetched.

```
images:[
{
SNO:'1',
NAME:'image.jpg',
PIC_NAME:'image'
}
]
```

When the images are uploaded, they are stored in a special folder in Nodejs, and from there, I'm extracting the images using an endpoint. Below is the Nodejs Code for that.

```
images.get('/Images/getImages/:slug', function(req, res) {
    var options = {
        root: path.join(__dirname, '/images')
    }
    res.sendFile(req.params.slug, options);
})
```

And below is the ReactJs code for fetching and showing the image in the web app:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './landingPage.css'
import Instance from "../Axios/Instance";
const Carousal = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchImages();
    }, [])
    async function fetchImages() {
        const result = await Instance.get('/carousalimages/getImages');
        setImages(result.data);
    }
    console.log(images);
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    {
                        images.map((pic) => {
                            return (
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <img src={`http://localhost:1200/Images/getImages/${pic.NAME}`} class="d-block w-100" alt={`${pic.PIC_NAME}`} />
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
            </div>

        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Carousal;
```

But don't know why the images are not loading in the app.

Comment: Why did you send the image file rather than the image data? Can you try `res.json(images)`

Comment: Lin Du, Okay will try like that.